# tcolorbox: Dynamic width and breakable

Tags: tcolorbox, page-breaking, width, dynamic

I'm trying to implement a kind of chat inside my document using `tcolorbox`. But I either can set the width dynamically or allow a pagebreak inside a "chat-message".

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tcbset{breakable, width=.8\linewidth, tcbox width=auto limited, size=title, arc=2mm, boxrule=.5pt, boxsep=1mm}

%page break possible
\newcommand{\coach}[1]{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow, sharp corners=northwest]#1\end{tcolorbox}}

%dynamic width
\newcommand{\klient}[1]{\tcbox[colback=green, sharp corners=southeast, flush right]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[2]
\coach{Hello World}
\klient{Hello World}

\coach{\blindtext[2]}
\klient{\blindtext[3]}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to meet both requirements?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome. I don't think this is possible. `auto limited` is an option for `\tcbox` only, as I understand the documentation, whereas `breakable` is a setting applicable to `\tcolorbox`es. These rely on different underlying structures, I think, so what's possible for one is not always possible for the other.

Comment: Thanks. I worked around with an `\ifdim` statement, comparing the textlength. This meets my requirements.

Comment: Perhaps you could post that as an answer? It might help somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If made a workaround with an `\ifdim` statement, which meets my requirements.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tcbset{breakable, width=.8\linewidth, tcbox width=auto limited, size=title, arc=2mm, boxrule=.5pt, boxsep=1mm}

\newlength{\mylen}

\newcommand{\coach}[1]{
    \def\content{#1}
    
    \settowidth{\mylen}{\content}
    \ifdim\mylen<.8\textwidth
        \tcbox[colback=yellow, sharp corners=northwest]{\content}
    \else 
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red, sharp corners=northwest]\content\end{tcolorbox}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[2]
\coach{Hello World}

\coach{\blindtext[2]}

\end{document}
```