# center and adapt width in tcolorbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox, width, center

## PROBLEM

So I'm finishing my `tcolorbox` styles for my writings, but I can't manage to center the text correctly if it is shorter than the `\linewidth`. One solution would be to add `\centering` every time, but it's not automatic, and I'm sure there's a better solution.

I also want that if the text is shorter than the `\linewidth` (as an example 3) center the box, and adapt de width of the box depending on the width of the text. Otherwise keep the `max width` the `\linewidth` and jump to a new line (with `\centering`).

In example 1, the centering is not build up correctly, instead of using `halgin=center` there should be like a `text=centered` (like `\centering`). And also, as it's shorter than the `\linewidth`, the width of the box should be adapted.

In example 3 the box should be centered, for this example I used `hbox`, which doesn't work if the text is larger than the `\linewidth`.

**So is there any way to combine the example 3 when the text is short (with the box centered), and the example 1 when the text is larger (with correct center)?**

## MWE

The `overlay=` is just in case the box is way to big, and needs to jump to another page the borders are not rounded (to know that the box hasn't finished).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}


\newtcolorbox{box1}[1]{title={\centering\large#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm, enhanced, breakable, colback=gray, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltitle=white, coltext=white, halign=center,
    overlay first={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
    overlay last={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);;}
}
\newtcolorbox{box2}[1]{title={\centering\large#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm, enhanced, breakable, colback=gray, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltitle=white, coltext=white,
    overlay first={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
    overlay last={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);;}
}
\newtcolorbox{box3}[1]{title={\centering\large#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm, enhanced, breakable, colback=gray, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltitle=white, coltext=white, hbox,
    overlay first={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
    overlay last={
        \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);;}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{box1}{Formula of $\sin(\theta)$}
$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\sin(\theta+2\pi k)=\sin(\theta)$
\end{box1}

\begin{box2}{Formula of $\sin(\theta)$}
$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\sin(\theta+2\pi k)=\sin(\theta)$
\end{box2}

\begin{box3}{Formula of $\sin(\theta)$}
$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\sin(\theta+2\pi k)=\sin(\theta)$
\end{box3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691486/tcolorbox-dynamic-width-and-breakable?rq=1 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595619/alignment-and-width-with-tcolorbox?rq=1 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below is based on OP's `box3` environment, with some changes:

- Option `breakable` is commented out since it's not supported when `hbox` is used.
- Option `varwidth upper` sets a max width for `hbox` box. It needs `varwidth` package.
- Option `halign title=flush center` centers the title, `before upper app=\centering` (needs tcolorbox library `hooks`) centers the (upper part) text, and `center` centers the box.

  - Here `halign=flush center` has no effect because the alignment is reset by the `varwidth` environment added by `varwidth upper` option.
  - Feasible values for `halign` and `halign title`, `flush center` and `center` are different. The first uses LaTeX `\centering` which sets `\rightskip0pt plus 1fil\leftskip0pt plus 1fil` (and more), while the latter (`center` alignment) sets `\centering` plus `\leftskip0pt plus2em\rightskip0pt plus2em\spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em \hbadness=10000\relax`. The differences will be noticeable when title text typesets in multiline.
    Because `halign=center` sets paragraph shape and interword spacing dimensions in relative units `em`, the effect of centering is influenced by the current font size, which makes
    `title={\large#1}, fonttitle=\large\bfseries,` and `title={#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries` slightly different.
    See related source lines [[1]](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/a67bce71d7ef76320e7815c62dd11eb415df4954/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L175-L178) and [[2]](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/a67bce71d7ef76320e7815c62dd11eb415df4954/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L436-L466) in `tcolorbox.sty` at v6.0.4.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, hooks, skins}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{box3}[1]{
  % hbox mode boxes are not breakable
  enhanced, % breakable,
  hbox, 
%  tcbox width=auto limited,
  center,
  varwidth upper,
  before upper app=\centering,
  halign title=flush center,
  title={#1}, fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
  toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm,
  boxrule=1pt,
  arc=2mm, rounded corners,
  colback=gray, colframe=black,
  coltitle=white, coltext=white,
  overlay first={
    \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
  overlay middle={
    \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
    \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
  overlay last={
    \draw[line width=1pt, black] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{box3}{Formula of $\sin(\theta)$}
  $\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\sin(\theta+2\pi k)=\sin(\theta)$
\end{box3}

\begin{box3}{Formula of $\sin(\theta)$}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{box3}

\begin{box3}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
  $\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\sin(\theta+2\pi k)=\sin(\theta)$
\end{box3}

\begin{box3}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{box3}

\newpage
\subsection*{\textsf{halign=center} vs \textsf{halign=flush center}}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  center, halign=center, fontupper=\Huge,
  title={\texttt{halign=center, fontupper=\string\Huge}}
]
  \leavevmode\llap{\smash{\rule{.4pt}{1em}}}Text Text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  center, halign=center, before upper=\Huge,
  title={\texttt{halign=center, before upper=\string\Huge}}
]
  \leavevmode\llap{\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4em}}}Text Text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[center, halign=center, title={\texttt{halign=center}}]
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[center, halign=flush center, title={\texttt{halign=flush center}}]
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: main output]
[image: "halign=center" vs "halign=flush center"]

Comment: Hmm my answer assumes `breakable` is not required, which is wrong.

Comment: using breakable doesn't cause any error until is required, do you think it might be possible to use breakable with an alternative of hbox which does the same? Or I should use 2 environments like `box` and `minibox`? (`minibox` with hbox, and `box` for breakable).

Comment: @Agente156 If your box content will never alter global statements or cause "side-effects", for example counter stepping and label creation, then you may use the box-measure-rebox scheme in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691921. Otherwise in general it's impossible to get a breakable tcolorbox with bounded-above variable width.

Comment: More precisely, only operations that cause global accumulating effects are problematic. For example, `\setcounter{<cnt>}{0}` acts global but not accumulating, but `\stepcounter{<cnt>}` meets.